# Javascript - Variable loose it's value after block

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can somebody explain me how to solve this problem?

```
let konyvSzam=0;

   db.checkPeldanySzam(rentISBN,(konyv) => {
        konyvSzam=konyv.Peldanyszam;
    });

    console.log("Nr of books");
    console.log(konyvSzam);
```

The variable gets the value but after I check it doesn't work

Comment: it is an asynchronous call

Comment: That's not a block, it is a function, and it isn't losing its value after it, it just doesn't have the new value before that function gets called.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly our DB call works asynchrous in node js and JavaScript try to enclose db calls in promise or use async/await .

Comment: Can you give me a little example, I'm quite new in this. Thank you.